# Getting a rewriterule syntax to be correct

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rewriterule to put into my .htaccess. What i need accomplished is:

https://a.b.com/?bunch_of_stuff

to become

https://www.b.com/?bunch_of_stuff

i.e., in the URL, I want to lose the subdomain part (the 'a.') and replace it with 'www'.

I've tried a bunch of stuff but i keep getting the original URL back. I'm sure this is easy and i'm just not seeing it, so perhaps a fresh pair of eyes can straighten this out.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.b\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.b.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hah! Brilliant! Yes, this works perfectly, and no, I hadn't tried this. I guess I forgot about RewriteCond and using it as you have. Excellent. Thanks so much. I'd upvote this but I don't have the required 15 points of reputation. But I wish you good karma for your help!